# High Cstack usage caused by ".print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)"

Tags: r, dplyr, stack-overflow

**The issue** -----

RStudio froze randomly when I used the pipe "%>%" with dplyr's functions (here the function "mutate").
After a few minutes, Rstudio printed this output :

```
Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit
```

**The traceback output** ------

When I glanced at the traceback, I saw a lot of repetitions of the line command ".print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)" :

```
..... (multiple repetitions of "XXX : .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)" with X from 966 to ...)
965: .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)
964: .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)
963: .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)
..... (multiple repetitions of "XXX : .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)" with X from 111 to 962)
10: .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)
9: .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)
8: .print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)
7: .print_helper_for_environment(x, all.names, 0)
6: print.environment(item$value)
5: print(item$value)
4: capture.output(environment(object))
3: .rs.getHelpFromObject(object, envir, name)
2: .rs.getHelpFunction(what, from)
1: (function (what, from, type) 
   {
       if (!length(type)) 
           return()
       if (grepl("|||", what, fixed = TRUE)) {
           splat <- strsplit(what, "|||", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
           from <- splat[[1]]
           what <- splat[[2]]
       }
       if (what == "install.packages" && type == .rs.acCompletionTypes$ARGUMENT && 
           is.null(from)) 
           return(.rs.getHelp("install.packages", "utils"))
       if (type == .rs.acCompletionTypes$OPTION) 
           return(.rs.getHelp("options", "base", subset = FALSE))
       if (type %in% c(.rs.acCompletionTypes$S4_GENERIC, .rs.acCompletionTypes$S4_METHOD)) {
           if (!is.null(help <- .rs.getHelp(paste(what, "methods", 
               sep = "-"), from))) 
               return(help)
           if (!is.null(help <- .rs.getHelp(what, from))) 
               return(help)
           return()
       }
       if (type %in% c(.rs.acCompletionTypes$FUNCTION, .rs.acCompletionTypes$S4_GENERIC, 
           .rs.acCompletionTypes$S4_METHOD, .rs.acCompletionTypes$R5_METHOD)) 
           return(.rs.getHelpFunction(what, from))
       else if (type == .rs.acCompletionTypes$ARGUMENT) 
           return(.rs.getHelpArgument(what, from, parent.frame()))
       else if (type == .rs.acCompletionTypes$PACKAGE) 
           return(.rs.getHelpPackage(what))
       else if (length(from) && length(what)) 
           return(.rs.getHelp(what, from))
       else return()
   })("mutate", ".conflicts", 6L)
```

I have googled the line ".print_helper_for_environment(val, all.names, count_depth + 1)". This function comes from the package RFast [(Link to the Rfast's function)](https://rdrr.io/cran/Rfast/src/R/s3operator.R). I used this package, but this issue also occurred when the package is detached.

**What is your opinion on the traceback? Thanks** ------

Comment: In the next update of Rfast I will remove this function. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks Manos Papadakis